# Can locked SOL be transfeered to new withdraw authority without custodian?

Tags: staking

I am trying to switch `--stake-authority` and `--withdraw-authority` of a locked stake account to a ledger from a hot wallet. I can use delegate stake to set a delegate but wondered about going further and moving it all to the ledger while leaving it locked. Can this be done without the custodian key?